# /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, macos

Want to convert my m4a files into mp3 files using a script. It would save some time... I have over 100 GB of music files.

OS: OSX10.14 / Terminal vs Bash script

I can run `ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i musicFile.m4a -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k musicFile.mp3` from the terminal. It converts the file and I can see and play the file from itunes.

When I run the same from a bash script it fails to convert.

`ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i $ENTRY_FILE -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k $MP3NAME`

My ipod nano just died and I got a new mp3 player. Now I need to convert my itunes files from AAC format to MP3. 
[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is an established video and music file converter.

When I run it from the bash script I tried a few things.

I added ./ in front of the file, that failed because it was installed under /usr/local/bin and not under the same directory.

I also tried sh ffmpeg... and that gave me the cannot execute a binary file.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# convert m4a file to mp3
set -e

file_convert() {
    ENTRY_FILE=$(printf %q "${entry}")
    FILE_NAME=$(printf %q "$(basename "${entry}")")
    DIR=$(printf %q "$(dirname "${entry}")")
    NAME="${FILE_NAME%.*}"
    EXT="${FILE_NAME##*.}"
    MP3NAME="${DIR}/${NAME}.mp3"

    printf "%*s%s\n"                    $((indent+2)) '' "$ENTRY_FILE"
    printf "%*s\tNew File :\t%s\n"      $((indent+2)) '' "$MP3NAME"

    if [ $EXT == "m4a" ]
    then
      printf "%*s\tConverting: \t%s\n" $((index+2)) '' "$ENTRY_FILE"
      ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i $ENTRY_FILE -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k $MP3NAME
    fi
}

walk() {
    local indent="${2:-0}"
    printf "\n%*s%s\n\n" "$indent" '' "$1"
    # If the entry is a file convert it
    for entry in "$1"/*; do [[ -f "$entry" ]] && file_convert; done
    # If the entry is a directory recurse
    for entry in "$1"/*; do [[ -d "$entry" ]] && walk "$entry" $((indent+2)); done
}

# If the path is empty use the current, otherwise convert relative to absolute; Exec walk()
[[ -z "${1}" ]] && ABS_PATH="${PWD}" || pushd "${1}" && ABS_PATH="${PWD}"
walk "${ABS_PATH}"
popd
echo
```

I expect `>./aacToMp3.sh ./music` to traverses the music directory and convert each m4a file to .mp3.

It is walking the file system and printing out correct files, with the spaces escaped. When it hits the ffmpeg line it halts. I put the set -e at the top of the file to force it to fail if the command fails. Without the set -e it happily walks all the music files and prints them to the stdout.

Comment: Strip your program until the problem remains.

Comment: put `echo $ENTRY_FILE`  and `echo $MP3NAME` before calling `ffmpeg`  and verify that they are getting proper value assigned to them before ffmpeg gets to it

Comment: Quote variables.

Comment: Did you install `ffmpeg` with **homebrew**? If so, it'll be in `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`.

Comment: If you have 100GB, you should consider using **GNU Parallel**, especially on a Mac which will likely have many CPU cores and fast, flash disk.

Comment: `sh ffmpeg` expects `ffpmeg` to be a shell script, not a binary executable. Why would you think that would work?

Comment: What error is it getting when it hits the `ffmpeg` line?

Comment: Your two `for entry` loops should instead be one `for` loop containing `if/elif` tests. That will keep the contents of each directory from being scanned twice. Avoid the temptation to chain `&&` and `||` - use `if` blocks instead. Never use `set -e`. You can use `set -x` to trace the execution and show you whether variables are getting the values you expect.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, fyi, GNU Parallel isn't required here, one should be able to achieve the same thing with `xargs -P`.

Comment: @ghoti I am not sure how you strip and replace extensions with `xargs` and it is so simple with `parallel`. Please post an `xargs` answer if you feel like it - I'm always happy to learn! I wasn't really saying `parallel` was *required*, I was just suggesting it will likely be faster, simpler and much less error-prone than a page of `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have lots of files to process and a decent multi-core CPU and fast disk, I would recommend **GNU Parallel** which you can install with **homebrew**:

```
brew install parallel
```

Then make a copy of a few files in a test directory and try:

```
parallel --dry-run ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k {.}.mp3 ::: *.m4a
```

If that looks good, replace `--dry-run` with `--progress`.

If that looks good, you can (make a backup first) and do the whole lot:

```
find path/to/music -name "*.m4a" -print0 | parallel -0 --progress ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k {.}.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the input.

After a while I ended up writing all the ffmpeg lines to a script file. Glad I did. I was able to quickly scan the file and see some errors and fix them.
This is what I came up with.
Basically I am writing straight text to stdout and directing it to a file. Which I converted to a shell script to convert each file. One at a time. Ran the generated script overnight.

```sh
file_convert() {
    ENTRY_FILE=$(printf %q "${entry}")
    FILE_NAME=$(printf %q "$(basename "${entry}")")
    DIR=$(printf %q "$(dirname "${entry}")")
    NAME="${FILE_NAME%.*}"
    EXT="${FILE_NAME##*.}"
    MP3NAME="${DIR}/${NAME}.mp3"

    if [ $EXT == "m4a" ]
    then
      printf 'echo "Converting %s ..."\n' "$FILE_NAME"
      printf 'ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i %s -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k %s\n\n' "$ENTRY_FILE" "$MP3NAME"
    fi
}
```

The output looked like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Converting 03\ It\'s\ Not\ My\ Time.m4a ..."
ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i /Users/arthuranderson/Documents/work/projects/mp3Convert/music/3\ Doors\ Down/3\ Doors\ Down\ \(Bonus\ Track\ Version\)/03\ It\'s\ Not\ My\ Time.m4a -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k /Users/arthuranderson/Documents/work/projects/mp3Convert/music/3\ Doors\ Down/3\ Doors\ Down\ \(Bonus\ Track\ Version\)/03\ It\'s\ Not\ My\ Time.mp3

echo "Converting 01\ Down.m4a ..."
ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i /Users/arthuranderson/Documents/work/projects/mp3Convert/music/311/Greatest\ Hits\ \'93-\'03/01\ Down.m4a -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 320k /Users/arthuranderson/Documents/work/projects/mp3Convert/music/311/Greatest\ Hits\ \'93-\'03/01\ Down.mp3
```

Mark I will try parallel when I purchase some more music next time.

Thanks everyone!